# pandas how to drop rows base on different columns and different conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df,you can get it by copy this code:

```
from io import StringIO
df = """
      RateCompany   gs  RB  ValIssueDate
 115    T           G   54  19580101
 116    T           G   54  19870101
 336    T           S   54  19580101
 337    T           S   54  19870101
 338    T           j   53  19970101
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep='\s+')
```

Now I want drop all the rows that has same RateCompany,gs,RB ,but ValIssueDate is larger than other row.

The output should be:

```
 RateCompany    gs  RB  ValIssueDate
         115    T           G   54  19580101
         336    T           S   54  19580101
         338    T           j   53  19970101
```

Any friend can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort by the columns you want to compare, then drop_duplicates on the key columns:

```
df.sort_values('ValIssueDate').drop_duplicates(['RateCompany', 'gs', 'RB'])
```

Output:

```
    RateCompany gs  RB  ValIssueDate
115           T  G  54      19580101
336           T  S  54      19580101
338           T  j  53      19970101
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply ,but I think this method is not safe enough ,because it will always drop the second row, if I change the order of the rows it will not work.

Comment: @William - `sort_values` sets the order as needed before dropping duplicates. This answer will work regardless of the order of your rows.

Comment: @William are you sure?

Comment: just curious sort_values will  always get the smaller value one by default ?

Comment: @William yes, there's an option `ascending` which defaults to `True`.

Comment: @QuangHoang awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using `idxmin()`

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['RateCompany', 'gs', 'RB'])['ValIssueDate'].idxmin()]


     RateCompany   gs   RB  ValIssueDate
115            T    G   54  19580101
336            T    S   54  19580101
338            T    j   53  19970101
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply ,and it works ,but not the fastest ,thanks again.

Comment: @William this could be faster on larger datasets, sorting is unnecessary and has a worse time complexity.  If you're only interested in one row, sorting is a usually unnecessary code smell.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `groupby` with `min`:

```
>>> df.groupby(["RateCompany", "gs", "RB"], as_index=False)["ValIssueDate"].min()

  RateCompany gs  RB  ValIssueDate
0           T  G  54      19580101
1           T  S  54      19580101
2           T  j  53      19970101
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply ,and it works ,but not the fastest ,thanks again.